# Deferred observable call

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have 5 observables say

```
Observable<String> obs1 = getObs1();
Observable<String> obs2 = getObs2();
Observable<String> obs3 = getObs3();
Observable<String> obs4 = getObs4();
Observable<String> obs5 = getObs5();
```

The implementation of `getObsX()` is to do a network call through RxNetty.

Since all are independent calls I need to start them at the same time.

On completion of `obs1` and `obs2`, I need to start call `getObs6()` which depends on `obs1` and `obs2`. I can do something like this.

```
    Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, (obs1, obs2) -> {
        return getObs6()
    })

;
```

Once I get `obs6`, then I need to use `obs1`, `obs2`, `obs3`, `obs4`, `obs5` and `obs6` to fetch `obs7`.

So how can I subscribe `obs1` twice, once to get `obs5` and another

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I'm not a Java developer so I'll give you the answer in c# - I hope that's OK.

It's as simple as doing this:

```
var query =
    from i1 in getObs1()
    from i2 in getObs2()
    from i3 in getObs3()
    from i4 in getObs4()
    from i5 in getObs5()
    from i6 in getObs6(i1, i2)
    from i7 in getObs7(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6)
    select i7;
```

I tested this with the following code:

```
IObservable<int> getObs1() => Observable.Return(1);
IObservable<int> getObs2() => Observable.Return(2);
IObservable<int> getObs3() => Observable.Return(3);
IObservable<int> getObs4() => Observable.Return(4);
IObservable<int> getObs5() => Observable.Return(5);
IObservable<int> getObs6(int x, int y) => Observable.Return(x * y);
IObservable<int> getObs7(params int[] x) => Observable.Return(x.Aggregate((j, k) => j * k));
```

I got the correct answer of `240`.